# PHP: Get all array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hi not so much experienced wiht php so need help.

I am trying to get list from array but it is only giving me first array item and not all

Here is my code

**I am getting this from my database query**

```
Array ( [item] => hot, categories, activity )
```

below is my foreach loop

```
$sorted = $order;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sorted);
echo '</pre>';

$temp_nav = array(); 
foreach ($sorted as $key) { 
    if(isset($navigation[$key])) 
        $temp_nav[$key] = $navigation[$key]; 
} 
$navigation = $temp_nav; 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($navigation);
echo '</pre>';
```

**$order print_r result is here**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hot
    [1] => categories
    [2] => activity
)
```

**Now result I am getting from `print_r($sorted);` is as below**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hot
    [1] => categories
    [2] => activity
)
```

But when I checked in foreach loop it is only outputing only fist item as below

**Below rewsult for $navigation**

```
Array
(
    [hot] = Array
        (
            [url] => ./url
            [lable] => Hot Items
        )
)
```

But I want only value like below

```
array(
    'hot',
    'categories',
    'activity'
)
```

So how can I write the code so it gives me result **with all item** but not only first item

Comment: You got them already ? Try using [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) or maybe [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys.php)

Comment: Your loop seems correct, maybe `$navigation['categories']` and `$navigation['activity']` aren't set?

Comment: get aray_keys from $navigation array and than loop through it and compare whether isset

Comment: I have added $order print_r please check edited question

Comment: thanks all of you but @Dinesh can you please give me some hit how to do?

Comment: can you give the value of $navigation array that seems to be necessary before any solutions can b give

Comment: @miorel but than how can I index those? as this is dynamic coming from database and it can be different more or less

Comment: @DeepakSrinivasan Do you need $navigation array? but its already there.. isn't it?

Comment: value of  $naivagation before for each loop begins.i think your navagation array has only 'hot'.so print it near $sorted

Comment: I have added in my question already please see this `Array
(
    [0] => hot
    [1] => categories
    [2] => activity
)`

Answer (score 0):

you are filtering by

```
if(isset($navigation[$key]))
```

and as shown its obvious that `$navigation` has only the key 'hot' from the list `{'hot','categories','activity'}`

if My assumption was wrong please provide us with the output of `print_r($navigation)`

Comment: so how can I add other items in $navigation? can you please help me to provide little of code to understand.. I am not so expert so need some proper guideline.. I will appreciate that..

Comment: first of all please show me what $navigation's content, and simply on a previous stage just add to it just by `$navigation['categories']=...`

Comment: I can't manually pass the index key as it is all dynamic coming from database and now there are three but it could be more or less

Comment: then the issue is with your Database query because its returning only one item.

Comment: I am getting this from my query `Array ( [item] => hot, categories, activity ) `

Comment: please provide us with the code that fill the `$navigation` array

Comment: I need to find into the system.. I am using CMS

Comment: I'm so sorry sir, I find my self unable to help you in this case.

Comment: Sorry away for a while.. I am finding and will post soon

Comment: when I passing manually array in $order like `$order = array('hot', 'categories', 'activity');` than it works but not by above code.. why?

Answer (score 0):

if I am assuming this is what you want to achieve..

```
$order= array("hot","categories","activity");
$navigation= array(
         "hot" => array("url"=> "some url", "label" => "some label"),
         "categories" => array("url"=> "some url", "label" => "some label")
   );

  $navigation_keys = array_keys($navigation);
  $array_final = array_intersect($order, $navigation_keys);

  print_r($array_final);
```

this will print:

```
Array ( [0] => hot [1] => categories )
```

explanation:
if you want to check if keys from your navigation array exists in your order array you can can create a new array of keys using array_keys and than do intersect which will only create an array of the keys which exists in your order array.

Comment: what exactly I am looking is this array(
    'hot',
    'categories',
    'activity'
) so I want to passing this order in foreach loop as a $sorted and it will sort this according to array set as above

Comment: if hot categories and activity exists inside your navigation array it will fetch them and than you can call any sorting algorithm over it

Comment: Yes, this is my db query result `Array ( [item] => hot, categories, activity ) `